# pyspark- why extracted json value are all null

Tags: pyspark

i have a csv file which has a column named 'jsonColumn'. below is a sample data.

```
jsonColumn
{"page":"mainpage","_timestamp":"2022-11-22T10:47:45.8060+01:00","object":"object1","destination":"destination1","subObject":"subObject1","type":"event"}
...
```

now i want to extract several fields from the jsonColumn, the expected result is

```
_timestamp,page,object,subObject
2022-11-22T10:47:45.8060+01:00,mainpage,object1,subObject1
...
```

Here is the code i used, but the why all the extracted fields' value are null?

```
%python
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession 
from pyspark.sql.functions import get_json_object

spark=SparkSession.builder.appName('practice').getOrCreate()

df2 = spark.read.csv('/FileStore/test1.csv', header=True)

df2_extractJSON = df2.withColumn("_timestamp", get_json_object(df2.jsonColumn, "$._timestamp"))\
                     .withColumn("page", get_json_object(df2.jsonColumn, "$.page"))\
                     .withColumn("object", get_json_object(df2.jsonColumn, "$.object"))\
                     .withColumn("subObject", get_json_object(df2.jsonColumn, "$.subObject"))

                     
df2_extractJSON.show()
```

The result are all null.

[image]

original dataframe is not empty. Please refer to jsonColumn in below screenshot, it's not empty.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the root cause is that there's additional double quote added when reading the csv. below code can fix this issue.

df2 = spark.read.csv('/FileStore/test1.csv', escape='"',header=True)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I've executed your code and it works fine for me:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession 
from pyspark.sql.functions import get_json_object

df2 = spark.createDataFrame([('''{"page":"mainpage","_timestamp":"2022-11-22T10:47:45.8060+01:00","object":"object1","destination":"destination1","subObject":"subObject1","type":"event"}''',)], "jsonColumn: string")

df2_extractJSON = df2.withColumn("_timestamp", get_json_object(df2.jsonColumn, "$._timestamp"))\
                     .withColumn("page", get_json_object(df2.jsonColumn, "$.page"))\
                     .withColumn("object", get_json_object(df2.jsonColumn, "$.object"))\
                     .withColumn("subObject", get_json_object(df2.jsonColumn, "$.subObject"))

                     
df2_extractJSON.show()
+--------------------+--------------------+--------+-------+----------+
|          jsonColumn|          _timestamp|    page| object| subObject|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------+-------+----------+
|{"page":"mainpage...|2022-11-22T10:47:...|mainpage|object1|subObject1|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------+-------+----------+
```

Have you checked if `df2` read data in correctly? It might be the case that the initial DataFrame is empty, so that's why you end up with NULLs when trying to extract the data.

Comment: Hi Bartosz - the initial DataFrame is not empty. I have verified that there's a row data in it. I have put a screenshot in this ticket. Actually, I am Azure databrick->notebook to run the pyspark code. the json string actually is put in a column of a csv file.  I copyied youcode into notebook, and does not return 'null' value to me. I see the only difference is that you're creating a dataframe by sample data, but I am reading a csv file which is uploaded to FileStore

Comment: I observe that there's additional double quotes added for the json string. that should be why all extracted fields are null. why it will automatically add additional double quotes when reading csv by pyspark??